# Return fields by comparing to array of objects using Map Filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-map

Try to return field of `array1` and another field of `array2`, on comparison.

I have two array of objects (client and customer). I want to return client id and customer name where customer id is equal to client id.For this purpose I want to use map,filter,but can't figure out how can I use here below is my try,

```
       let clientcontract=this.state.addclient.filter(client=>{
        return(
            this.state.customer.filter(cust=>{
                return (
                    cust.id===client.id  // comparing customer and client id
                )
            })
        )
    });
```

This approach is used to get the field where both id of customer and client are same but didn't know how I can get customer name and client id and return in client contract, as I am using filter first time so facing problem in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function inside the `filter()` function. And finally to get the *customer name*, use a `map()` function - see below:

```
let clientcontract=this.state.customer.filter(cust => {
    return this.state.addclient.some(client => {
        return cust.id === client.id  // comparing customer and client id
    });
}).map(cust => cust.name);
```

Comment: But how can I return customer name and client id in clientcontract when condition is true?

Comment: `clientcontract` will be an array of values from `addclient` then satisfies the condition - perhaps you'll need to swap `this.state.addclient` and `this.state.customer` around

Comment: @MuhammadNabeel you get a filtered list of `addclient` elements that *is* a customer...

Comment: as JaromandaX says if you want to get customer, you can just switch the `addclient` and `customer`...

Comment: yes I got customer filtered result,e.g customer-{id:1,name:"abc",age:4}, But I want to return only name="abc" got from filtered result and client id on which it is compared to clientcontract,how can I map filter then?

Comment: @MuhammadNabeel see updated answer... you can use a `map()` function after the `filter`

Comment: yes I have got the name but I also want to get the client id as well on which it was filtered.

Comment: can you post your json arrays too ?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanUlHaq,  its just like this , customer-{id:1,name:"abc",age:4}, client:{1,3} (where 3 is customer id) in client array

Comment: @MuhammadNabeel client is an object not an array
can you please make sure what is format of data in client ?